# Trailing 30 day summing and case logic

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL table that has three columns: customer_id, the date of their first order, and the date of their last order. I am trying to create a report that shows a percentage of existing customers who re-ordered in the last 30 days...i.e. if a customer's first order is before 30 days ago, and their last order is within the last 30 days, they count in the numerator. If the customer's first order is before 30 days ago, then they count in the denominator.

I want the output to be just two columns: 1) the dates going reverse chronologically, and 2) the percentage of customers that meet the above criteria for that date. I cannot seem to figure out how to build this report.

Does anyone know how to start with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` for this.

```
select avg(case when last_order_date >= dateadd(day, -30, current_date) then 1.0 else 0 end)
from t
where first_order_date < dateadd(day, -30, current_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

cool, so it's a "getting two results from one place and then combining the results" query? If you can guarantee a customer table with unique customer_id, this should work.  I think a percentage approach of a total for the day will work better than a numerator/denominator, because wouldn't there be days with 0 "new" customers and days with zero "old" customers?

I'm also not completely clear, what is more important, new customers or old customers? This provides a percentage of new customers, you can switch things around as needed to show percentage of old customers.

```
------- just some fake data - you won't need this because you have the real thing
WITH  CUSTOMER_TABLE AS     (

SELECT   1  AS customer_id  ,   CAST('2017-08-01' AS  DATE) AS first_order_date  ,  CAST('2018-07-05' AS DATE)  AS  last_order_date   UNION
SELECT   2   ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-06'    UNION
SELECT   3   ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-07'    UNION
SELECT   4   ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-08'    UNION
SELECT   5   ,  '2018-06-01'   , '2018-07-09'    UNION
SELECT   6   ,  '2018-05-31'   , '2018-07-10'    UNION
SELECT   7   ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-11'    UNION
SELECT   8   ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-12'    UNION
SELECT   9   ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-13'    UNION
SELECT   10  ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-14'    UNION
SELECT   11  ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-15'    UNION
SELECT   12  ,  '2018-03-04'   , '2018-07-16'    UNION
SELECT   13  ,  '2018-01-01'   , '2018-07-17'    UNION
SELECT   14  ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-17'    UNION
SELECT   15  ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-17'    UNION
SELECT   16  ,  '2018-01-01'   , '2018-07-18'    UNION
SELECT   17  ,  '2018-02-01'   , '2018-07-18'    UNION
SELECT   18  ,  '2018-07-02'   , '2018-07-18'    UNION
SELECT   19  ,  '2018-07-01'   , '2018-07-18'    

)


SELECT   last_order_date  ,  
------ note the "1.00" forcing PostgreSQL to return a decimal result
1.00 * (count_of_new_customers)/(count_of_old_customers + count_of_new_customers ) AS percentage_of_new_customers , 
count_of_old_customers  ,   count_of_new_customers    ,
count_of_old_customers + count_of_new_customers AS total_customers_for_the_day   

FROM

(
SELECT last_order_date   ,
CAST(COUNT (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,   first_order_date , last_order_date)  > 30 THEN 'old customer'  END  ) AS integer)   AS  count_of_old_customers  ,
CAST(COUNT (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,   first_order_date , last_order_date)  <= 30 THEN 'new customer'  END ) AS integer)   AS  count_of_new_customers 
----replace  CUSTOMER_TABLE with your actual schema.table
FROM        CUSTOMER_TABLE
GROUP BY  last_order_date 
)

-----  here is the descending last_order_date you wanted
ORDER BY   last_order_date    DESC
```